# Spring Batch: Late-binding of commit-interval gives error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-batch

I am trying to late-binding of commit-interval in spring batch and have had no success. The below is the working code without late binding.

```
@Bean
public BatchProcessingService batchProcessingService(JobLauncher jobLauncher, Job importQuestionsJob) {
    return new BatchProcessingServiceImpl(jobLauncher, importQuestionsJob);
}

@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
    final SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    final SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor);
    return jobLauncher;
}

@Bean(name = IMPORT_QUESTION_JOB_LABEL)
public Job importQuestionsJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step validateFile,
                              Step questionsUpload, QuestionJobListener questionJobListener) {
    return jobs.get(IMPORT_QUESTION_JOB_LABEL)
            .listener(questionJobListener)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(validateFile)
            .next(questionsUpload)
            .end()
            .preventRestart()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step questionsUpload(StepBuilderFactory steps, QuestionReader questionReader, TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
                            QuestionProcessor questionProcessor, QuestionWriter questionWriter, BackOffPolicy backOffPolicy,
                            ApplicationProperties properties) {
    return steps.get("QUESTION_UPLOAD")
            .<Question, Question>chunk(properties.getChunkSize())
            .faultTolerant()
            .processorNonTransactional()
            .retry(RetriableException.class)
            .retryLimit(3)
            .backOffPolicy(backOffPolicy)
            .skip(WebApplicationException.class)
            .skipLimit(10000000)
            .reader(questionReader)
            .processor(questionProcessor)
            .writer(questionWriter)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
            .throttleLimit(properties.getThrottleLimit())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step validateFile(StepBuilderFactory steps, ValidationTasklet validationTasklet) {
    return steps.get("TASK_UI_VALIDATION")
            .tasklet(validationTasklet)
            .build();
}


@Bean
public QuestionFieldSetMapper questionFieldSetMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return new QuestionFieldSetMapper(objectMapper);
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public QuestionReader questionReader(QuestionFieldSetMapper questionFieldSetMapper) {
    return new QuestionReader(questionFieldSetMapper);
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public QuestionProcessor questionProcessor(ImageService imageService, FileService fileService, UploadClient uploadClient,
                                           ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return new QuestionProcessor(imageService, fileService, uploadClient, objectMapper);
}


@Bean
@StepScope
public QuestionWriter questionWriter(UploadClient uploadClient, FileService fileService) {
    return new QuestionWriter(uploadClient, fileService);
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public ValidationTasklet validationTasklet(ValidationService validationService) {
    return new ValidationTasklet(validationService);
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public QuestionCSVTasklet questionCSVTasklet(QuestionCSVService questionCSVService) {
    return new QuestionCSVTasklet(questionCSVService);
}

@Bean
@JobScope
public QuestionJobListener questionJobListener(StepFailureDetailsRepository stepFailureDetailsRepository) {
    return new QuestionJobListener(stepFailureDetailsRepository);
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(ApplicationProperties applicationProperties) {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(applicationProperties.getCorePoolSize());
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(applicationProperties.getMaxPoolSize());
    return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
}

@Bean
public BackOffPolicy backOffPolicy() {
    ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(1000L);
    return backOffPolicy;
}
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#late-binding) I tried to set the late-binding as follows:

```
@Bean
@JobScope
public Step questionsUpload(StepBuilderFactory steps, QuestionReader questionReader, TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
                            QuestionProcessor questionProcessor, QuestionWriter questionWriter, BackOffPolicy backOffPolicy,
                            ApplicationProperties properties, @Value("#{jobParameters['commitInterval']}") long chunkSize) {
    return steps.get("QUESTION_UPLOAD")
            .<Question, Question>chunk((int) chunkSize)
            .faultTolerant()
            .processorNonTransactional()
            .retry(RetriableException.class)
            .retryLimit(3)
            .backOffPolicy(backOffPolicy)
            .skip(WebApplicationException.class)
            .skipLimit(10000000)
            .reader(questionReader)
            .processor(questionProcessor)
            .writer(questionWriter)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
            .throttleLimit(properties.getThrottleLimit())
            .build();
}
```

I tried the above and I am getting error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'uploadsResource' defined in file [/Users/putty/Projects/Playment/Shadowfax/uploads/build/classes/main/in/playment/csvupload/upload/UploadsResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'uploadService' defined in class path resource [in/playment/csvupload/config/ApplicationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'uploadService' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchProcessingService' defined in class path resource [in/playment/csvupload/config/QuestionBatchJobConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'batchProcessingService' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'importQuestionsJob' defined in class path resource [in/playment/csvupload/config/QuestionBatchJobConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'importQuestionsJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.questionsUpload': Scope 'job' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at in.playment.csvupload.CsvUploadApplication.main(CsvUploadApplication.java:15) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'uploadService' defined in class path resource [in/playment/csvupload/config/ApplicationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'uploadService' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchProcessingService' defined in class path resource [in/playment/csvupload/config/QuestionBatchJobConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'batchProcessingService' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'importQuestionsJob' defined in class path resource [in/playment/csvupload/config/QuestionBatchJobConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'importQuestionsJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.questionsUpload': Scope 'job' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchProcessingService' defined in class path resource [in/playment/csvupload/config/QuestionBatchJobConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'batchProcessingService' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'importQuestionsJob' defined in class path resource [in/playment/csvupload/config/QuestionBatchJobConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'importQuestionsJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.questionsUpload': Scope 'job' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'importQuestionsJob' defined in class path resource [in/playment/csvupload/config/QuestionBatchJobConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'importQuestionsJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.questionsUpload': Scope 'job' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'importQuestionsJob' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.questionsUpload': Scope 'job' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.questionsUpload': Scope 'job' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:355) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.getName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.FlowBuilder.createState(FlowBuilder.java:282) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.FlowBuilder.doNext(FlowBuilder.java:255) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.FlowBuilder.next(FlowBuilder.java:111) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at in.playment.csvupload.config.QuestionBatchJobConfig.importQuestionsJob(QuestionBatchJobConfig.java:75) ~[main/:na]
    at in.playment.csvupload.config.QuestionBatchJobConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f7219f37.CGLIB$importQuestionsJob$2(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at in.playment.csvupload.config.QuestionBatchJobConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f7219f37$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ac4c319d.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at in.playment.csvupload.config.QuestionBatchJobConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f7219f37.importQuestionsJob(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.JobScope.getContext(JobScope.java:159) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.JobScope.get(JobScope.java:92) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 79 common frames omitted
```

TLDR: How to late-binding of commit-interval with SpringBatch?

Comment: I highly doubt you can, nor that you should be doing that.

Comment: @M.Deinum This is one such answer that hinted that it was possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373110/spring-batch-javaconfig-parameterize-commit-interval-aka-chunksize . I have seen lot of posts that have pointed out to similar solutions