# In a read-write chunk oriented process where does Spring Batch commit?

Tags: java, spring-batch, commit, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

On my java project, I am having a read (`FlatFileItemReader`) - write (`JdbcBatchItemWriter`) chunk oriented process using Spring boot. Using `HikariCp` datasources.

Looking into the Spring batch jdbc writer we can find that part :

```
               //some code
                @Override
                public int[] doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                    for (T item : items) {
                        itemPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(item, ps);
                        ps.addBatch();
                    }
                    return ps.executeBatch();
                }
              //some code
```

So basically here if my Hikari datasource has `setAutocommit` parameter to **true** it means that after `ps.executeBatch()` my database will be updated.

First question here, on `PreparedStatement.executeBatch()` **how does it process exactly?** Does it commit every sql statement or at the end of every sql statements?

In the case where `setAutocommit` parameter is on **false**, after `ps.executeBatch()` it should not be updated.

Since Spring batch should manage the transaction and so the commit. I tried to find where does it commit for a better understanding on an issue that I have. Looking to `ChunkOrientedTasklet`, `SimpleChunkProcessor` and `TransactionTemplate`I could not find where in the process it does the commit.

So my second question is, **where does Spring batch exactly commit on a chunk oriented process?**

**EDIT** :  Using Spring batch 3.0.7

**EDIT** : It seems processed in `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status)` but still can not understand how.

Answer (score 1):

Your autocommit parameter is irrelevant, Spring will manage things and override that as it sees fit (and it does see it fit).

You can [set the commit interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373110/spring-batch-javaconfig-parameterize-commit-interval-aka-chunksize) to define how often you want to commit.

Whether you should change it depends entirely on how you intend to batch, whether your execution can fail, whether those cases should be skipped or retried and other such things.

Comment: Well somehow in my case the parameter autocommit being to **true**, database is updated, and being to **false**, database is not even though Spring should manage it. I know that I can set the chunk size and so the commit interval, I did it by `StepBuilderFactory.get("myJob").<a,b>chunk(100).//stuff`

Comment: Then it sounds like you don't have all the settings correct. Make sure your `PlatformTransactionManager` is configured properly, etc.

Comment: Well then I cant figure what ? `@Autowired
private ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager;

@Bean
public ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() {
 return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
}`

Comment: anyway it is a bit out of the question subject

Comment: Not at all. If you look at `ResourcelessTransactionManager`, you'll see that `commit()` and `rollback()` methods are no-ops. You're using the wrong manager.

Comment: Ok got it that is why I could not find out the exact commit() line. I did use it to prevent Spring to write anything in the database and only use memory with a map. Which TransactionManager should I use for this purpose then ?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question on "when is it committed?", per the [Spring Batch docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html):

> **5.1 Chunk-Oriented Processing**
>
> Spring Batch uses a 'Chunk Oriented' processing style within its most
> common implementation. Chunk oriented processing refers to reading the
> data one at a time, and creating 'chunks' that will be written out,
> within a transaction boundary. One item is read in from an ItemReader,
> handed to an ItemProcessor, and aggregated. Once the number of items
> read equals the commit interval, the entire chunk is written out via
> the ItemWriter, and then the transaction is committed.

[image]

> Below is a code representation of the same concepts shown above:
>
> ```
> List items = new Arraylist();
> for(int i = 0; i < commitInterval; i++){
>     Object item = itemReader.read()
>     Object processedItem = itemProcessor.process(item);
>     items.add(processedItem);
> }
> itemWriter.write(items);
> ```

Hence, if you're going to use Spring Batch, you shouldn't be messing with setting auto-commit, as this is something you should trust the framework to handle for you. The section immediately below that shows an example of how this is configured:

> **5.1.1 Configuring a Step**
>
> Despite the relatively short list of required dependencies for a Step,
> it is an extremely complex class that can potentially contain many
> collaborators. In order to ease configuration, the Spring Batch
> namespace can be used:
>
> ```
> <job id="sampleJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
>     <step id="step1">
>         <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
>             <chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="10"/>
>         </tasklet>
>     </step>
> </job>
> ```
>
> The configuration above represents the only required dependencies to
> create an item-oriented step:
>
> - reader - The ItemReader that provides items for processing.
> - writer - The ItemWriter that processes the items provided by the    ItemReader.
> - transaction-manager - Spring's PlatformTransactionManager that will    be used to begin and commit transactions during processing.
> - job-repository - The JobRepository that will be used to periodically    store the StepExecution and ExecutionContext during
>   processing (just    before committing). For an in-line  (one
>   defined within a    ) it is an attribute on the  element;
>   for a standalone    step, it is defined as an attribute of the
>   .
> - commit-interval - The number of items that will be processed before    the transaction is committed.

Comment: Well I already saw all that but I still can not figure out Spring batch committing logic inside the code.

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I'm not completely understanding what problem you're trying to solve exactly. What is your use case for "penetrating the black box" of Spring Batch and how it manages transactions internally? If I understand that, perhaps I could be of more help.

Comment: My problem is that when my Hikari datasource has autocommit to **false** Spring batch should still manage the commit, but it does not. So in my question I wanted to understand how does exactly works `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status)` to try to solve my current issue.

Comment: Ah, I see. So Hikari and Spring Batch are getting tangled up with one another and you're trying to troubleshoot that. Hmm, that's a bit more difficult.

Comment: Yeah but it seems that I made a TransactionManager configuration mistake, check @Kayaman comments

Comment: Ah okay. Well, I hope that has you barking up the right tree so that you are able to get it solved!